# What is the meaning of max and offset pagination params in createcriteria?

Tags: grails

In [the Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html), we read:

```
def results = Book.list(max: 10, offset: 100)
```

- *max - The maximum number to list*
- *offset - The offset from the first result to list from*

Also, from [this MySQL tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx), we read: *the offset specifies the offset of the first row to return.*

Questions:

- **Is *max* the maximium number of rows per page?**
- **Could you give me an example about the *offset* meaning?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hello GORM, when you return me a list of `Book`s give me only 10 (max) results but do not start from the Zeroth (offset = 0) place, instead start listing results from 100th (offset) result.*

Comment: 10 books per page? What about if there are less than 100 books in the database?

Comment: @chelder If there are less than 100 books in the database then you would not get any result back. I would suggest to test that at least to witness the behavior. Grails console is provided for such testing. Use it for these kind of questions, it helps a lot. :)

Comment: Thank you. I just witness that `max` is the maximium PER PAGE. I'm interested in the Grails console. My console in Eclipse don't show that information (unless I write something like `println "variableX value is ${variableX}"`